# How to locate the input within div

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I got an issue reading XPath. Need some help/advise from experts.

Part of the HTML code:

```
<div id="nav-typeahead-wormhole">
    <div class="nav-search-typeahead">
        <artdeco-typeahead-deprecated id="nav-search-artdeco-typeahead" class="search-typeahead-v2 ember-view">
            <artdeco-typeahead-deprecated-input id="ember35" class="ember-view">
                <!---->
                <input role="combobox" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" placeholder="Recherche" type="text">
            </artdeco-typeahead-deprecated-input>
            <!---->
```

I try to select the input in the div `id="nav-typeahead-wormhole"` using Xpath

My code is the following:

```
search = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='nav-typeahead-wormhole']/input[1]")
```

I got this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='nav-typeahead-wormhole']/input[1]"}
```

Comment: try this xpath `//div[@id="nav-typeahead-wormhole"]//input[@placeholder="Recherche"]` OR it may depends on your previous actions if it is visible/clickable on page, try adding wait before performing action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired `<input>` element is [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/) based element so to identify the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  search = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#nav-typeahead-wormhole input[placeholder='Recherche']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  search = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='nav-typeahead-wormhole']//input[@placeholder='Recherche']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you very muck ! That's excatly what I needed. The other anwers work as well for this part, but further I was stuck again and the only wait to get through is your method.

Answer (score 2):

The `INPUT` element isn't a child of the `DIV` you reference in your locator as is implied with the `/` operator. `/` is child (one level down), `//` is any descendant (one or more levels down). So your XPath should be:

```
//div[@id='nav-typeahead-wormhole']//input[1]
```

Other alternatives are:

```
//div[@id='nav-typeahead-wormhole']/div//input
```

or

```
//artdeco-typeahead-deprecated[@id='nav-search-artdeco-typeahead']/artdeco-typeahead-deprecated-input/input
```

or

```
//artdeco-typeahead-deprecated/artdeco-typeahead-deprecated-input/input
```

or

```
//div[@id="nav-typeahead-wormhole"]//input[@placeholder="Recherche"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Xpath is slow. Try using css selectors:

```
#nav-typeahead-wormhole input
```